# O withJson() do SIim possui algum limite de caracteres para converter um array de objetos em Json

Tags: php, slim

Tenho um array com 700 objetos que está sendo carregado corretamente pelo PHP, mas ao hora de enviar a resposta para o navegador com o `return $response->withJson()` é mostrado o seguinte erro:

`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: end of data when ',' or ']' was expected at line 1 column 181244 of the JSON data`

Este erro ocorre justamente quando eu preciso visualizar os 700 objetos, quando visualizo somente 30 objetos, por exemplo, o Json é gerado corretamente.

Então queria saber se o `$response->withJson()` do Slim tem alguma limitação de caracteres que o impede de converter este array em um Json. Se tiver, qual seria a melhor forma para visualizar este array no formato Json pelo Slim?

Abaixo está uma parte do Json que é retornado pelo `withJson()`, no final do Json o `]` não foi adicionado pelo `$response->withJson()`:

```
[
    {
        "id":"700",
        "id_usuario":"1",
        "nome":"Empresa 1",
        "cnpj":"00.000.000\/0001-00",
        "contato":"Teste",
        "email":"teste@empresa.com.br",
        "telefone":"(11)00000000",
        "cidade":"Santo Andr\u00e9",
        "status":"ativado",
        "criado_em":"2016-09-14 10:20:22"
    },
    ...
    {
        "id":"1",
        "id_usuario":"1",
        "nome":"Empresa 2",
        "cnpj":"11.111.111\/0001-11",
        "contato":"Teste 2",
        "email":"teste@mperesa2.com.br",
        "telefone":"0000-0000",
        "cidade":"",
        "status":"ativado",
        "criado_em":"2010-12-08 10:20:13"
    }
```

Comment: Isso tá parecendo um erro de formatação do JSON, consegue postar o com 700 elementos?? (Edita na sua pergunta)

Comment: problema é que o erro pode estar em qualquer lugar do json, esses 2 ultimos objetos estao corretos, por isso passei o site que valida o json.

Comment: Não tenho como colocar os 700 objetos aqui porque cada objeto tem mais de 10 linhas e algumas contém informações reais, então adicionei somente o inicio e fim. E realmente é problema de formatação pelo o que vi, mas tem como corrigir isso utilizando o `$response->withJson()` do Slim?

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade isso é problema na formatação do JSON, alguma coisa sobrando ou faltando.

Eu uso um site chamado [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com) que ja aponta onde esta o erro, ai fica fácil resolver.

Comment: Passei o Json no site e o erro está na última linha, ficou faltando o `]` para fechar o array. Agora preciso saber o porque o `$response->withJson()` não está adicionando o `]` no final do Json.